# Difficulty using subprocess.check_output with command line argument in many parts

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a command line tool which I run as follows:

```
/home/user/Dennis --+-+--+-----+--+++-+-+-- --+-++-+---+--+--++-++++- +--+---++++-+++-++-+-++++ --+-----+---+--++++---++- ----+----++++++-++++---+- ----------++-----++------ +--++-+-++++---+++--+++++ +-+-----++-+++-----+++-++ -++++--+-++--++---++-+++- +--++++-++----+---+--++-+ +++----+--++-+++-+--+++++ -++++-+-++++-+++------+++ -++-++-+--++--+---+-+---+ +-+++---+---++--+++--+--+ ++-+-+--++--+-------+-+-- ---++--+-+--+-+++-+++---- -+---+++-------+++-+----- +-+--------++++++--+-++-+ ++++-+++++++++-----+++++- -+++++-+---+-++---++++--- +-+---+++-+---+-++--++--- +-+-++-++++-+---------+-+ +-+++---++-----+-+--+--++ ++++++-+-++--+----++-+-+- ---+--++--------+++--+---
-5258461839360
```

In other words it takes a long string of + and -s as its command line argument separated by spaces.   I am trying to call it from Python. In ipython I do:

```
In [1]: outstr = "--+-+--+-----+--+++-+-+-- --+-++-+---+--+--++-++++- +--+---++++-+++-++-+-++++ --+-----+---+--++++---++- ----+----++++++-++++---+- ----------++-----++------ +--++-+-++++---+++--+++++ +-+-----++-+++-----+++-++ -++++--+-++--++---++-+++- +--++++-++----+---+--++-+ +++----+--++-+++-+--+++++ -++++-+-++++-+++------+++ -++-++-+--++--+---+-+---+ +-+++---+---++--+++--+--+ ++-+-+--++--+-------+-+-- ---++--+-+--+-+++-+++---- -+---+++-------+++-+----- +-+--------++++++--+-++-+ ++++-+++++++++-----+++++- -+++++-+---+-++---++++--- +-+---+++-+---+-++--++--- +-+-++-++++-+---------+-+ +-+++---++-----+-+--+--++ ++++++-+-++--+----++-+-+- ---+--++--------+++--+---"

In [2]: from subprocess import check_output

In [3]: check_output(["/home/user/Dennis", outstr])
Out[3]: '-1\n'
```

My guess it is the spaces that are causing the problem.

How can I get the same output I would from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split `outstr` and pass splitted string within list to `check_call()`. Easiest way for making change in your current code will be to make it as:

```
from subprocess import check_call

outstr = "--+-+--+-----+--+++-+-+-- --+-++-+---+--+--++-++++- +--+---++++-+++-++-+-++++ --+-----+---+--++++---++- ----+----++++++-++++---+- ----------++-----++------ +--++-+-++++---+++--+++++ +-+-----++-+++-----+++-++ -++++--+-++--++---++-+++- +--++++-++----+---+--++-+ +++----+--++-+++-+--+++++ -++++-+-++++-+++------+++ -++-++-+--++--+---+-+---+ +-+++---+---++--+++--+--+ ++-+-+--++--+-------+-+-- ---++--+-+--+-+++-+++---- -+---+++-------+++-+----- +-+--------++++++--+-++-+ ++++-+++++++++-----+++++- -+++++-+---+-++---++++--- +-+---+++-+---+-++--++--- +-+-++-++++-+---------+-+ +-+++---++-----+-+--+--++ ++++++-+-++--+----++-+-+- ---+--++--------+++--+---"

check_call_args = ["/home/user/Dennis"] + outstr.split(' ')
check_call(check_call_args)
```

where `str.split(' ')` will split your string into list of substrings separated by space `' '`.